# value data not added to request on submit and label interference on the value

Tags: html, angularjs, materialize

i have got two issues..looking forward for solution
issue 1: I have a ui-calendar ,on clicking the any date a new form will be opened which will have two input forms as shown.

```js
app.controller("MyAddController", function($scope, $http) {
 $scope.test = {};
    $scope.add = function() {
     
     console.log("------------>"+JSON.stringify($scope.test));
     $http({
         url: "rest/leave/create",
         method: "POST",
         data: JSON.stringify($scope.test),
         headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            if (data) {
                $scope.data = data;
                alert("success");
            }
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("error");
        })
    }
});
```

```html
  <!-- Modal Structure -->
  <div id="modal1" class="modal" ng-controller="MyAddController">
    <div class="modal-content">
    
           <div class="row modal-form-row">
            <div class="input-field col s5">
              <input id="startDate" type="text" class="validate"  value="{{selectionDate.startdate1}}" readonly="true" ng-bind="test.startDate" >
 <label for="startDate">Start Date</label>
               
            </div>
            
            <div class="input-field col s5">
            
              <input id="endDate" type="text" class="validate"  value="{{selectionDate.enddate1}}" readonly="true" ng-bind="test.endDate">
<label for="endDate">End Date</label>
              
            </div>
   
          </div>
                      
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" ng-click="add()" name="action">Submit
    <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
  </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The problem with the above code is that the value of the input fields are not included while passing the data to the server as it was not typed.i want the field to be disabled ie not editable but the value from {{Selectdate.startdate}} and {{selectDate.endDate}} should be included in the request.So please let me know how to do this.(selectionDate is in $rootscope and test in $scope).

2.Second issue.

From the same code above ,with a label the value {{selectedDate.startDate1}} overlaps with the label text as shown below

[image]

How to make the label move up like other input fields.

Any kind of help would be appreciated

Comment: add an angular app and controller to your snippet and we can go from there

Comment: Everything has been added to the code ,still isn't working,..i mean on form submit data isn't included in the request

Comment: no it hasnt. the snippet you have here isnt even an angular app. you just have an HTML view... add the reference to angular, then add the javascript

Comment: edited my question.Hope it gives more clarity.And this file is included in another html where i hav defined ng-app.So havent included it here